# Foreach alters entities, which results in exception

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

In my seed method, I have the following:

```
foreach (var user in context.Users.ToList())
{
    //Empty block here
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Somehow I am getting an exception, that the entity `Profile` (a property inside of `User`) has its required field `Email` not set. How is this even possible, I have not made any changes.

If I comment out the `foreach` then the seed is successful.

Comment: Is it some kind of theoretical question? What's the point of empty `foreach`?

Comment: Its important to note that a `foreach` is literally a `while` loop over an iterator. It does nothing to modify the content of a collection.

Comment: It is not theoretical, I simplified everything during debugging. Code used to have complex logic inside of foreach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include your `Profile` navigation property to fetch it from db with `Users`:

```
foreach (var user in context.Users.Include("Profile").ToList())
```

Comment: How do I fetch all properties?

Comment: You can't. You have to specify each of them. Of course, you have to only do that for Navigation properties.